# Navigation Drawer list hide fragment

Tags: android

[image: bug]

when drawer list open , the left side fragment will be black , this fragment contains details text for the selected child , once drawer close , textview appear normally

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drawer's width should be no more between 240dp and 320dp, your drawer's width is probably "match_parent", change to 320dp and the navigation drawer should not hide your fragment anymore.

Take a look at [NavigationDrawer guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Style).

Hope it helps.